# A label or any component that moves from one place to another in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, event-dispatching

I am trying to move an label/icon & button from one place to another place using `setLocation` method but for some reason the objects are moving but not in motion. So if any one knows how to do this thing please tell me.

How to create a label or any component that moves from one place to another place in JFrame?

Below I have shown the code:

```
jl = JLabel
jf = JFrame

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource()==jbtn)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=30;i++)
            {
                jl.setLocation(100,100+i);
                jl.repaint();
                jf.repaint();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch(Exception ae)
                {
                    ae.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I am trying to move an label/icon & button from one place to another place"*  Why?  What feature does that provide to the user?  What layout does the parent container use?

Comment: i have kept the layout as null. I am trying to make an animation by moving the label. I am trying to make an animated login screen and for that purpose i want to know this thing.

Comment: *"animated login screen"*  Here's an idea.  ***Don't*** animate a log-in screen.  For log-ins and many other components, the users generally prefer the KISS principle of 'Keep It Simple, Stupid'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you are blocking the thread (the Event Dispatching Thread) responsible for painting the updates

You might like to have a read of [java timer change delay with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577707/java-timer-change-delay-with-button/13577984#13577984) and [Does displaying Java GUI requires some special treatment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577451/does-displaying-java-gui-requires-some-special-treatment/13577506#13577506) which shows animation in swing and discusses the importance of the EDT.

Comment: Owhhh i got it i'll try to use timer. Thanks